# How to change the value of a Switch in Frank / Calabash

Tags: ios, ruby, uiswitch, calabash, frank

I have a switch with a view, say 'switch_view'. I need to change it for an automation test. How do I do this? My work till now is:

```
def switch(switch_view)
    # Get the value of the switch
    switch_state = (frankly_map(switch_view, 'isON')).first
    switch_state[0] = !switch_state[0]
    touch(switch_view)
end
```

As you can see, this is just an amalgamation of all the stuff I have tried out till now and that damn switch has still not moved. Please do help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. But I thought I should leave it here since it might be the cause of quite some confusion. The key is to use the in-build tap_and_hold method.

```
def switch(switch_view)
  tap_and_hold(switch_view)
  sleep 1 # For the animation
end
```

You can combine this with prior information about the state and create definite tests as well.